# Mysql php - web app scale? (What means large?)

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications, hosting, large-data

I'm working on a web app, and i already have a hosting. I made some websites and apps for my clients (quite small traffic), but now i would like to create a web app which is free to use, so i expect 5000+ users.

I read a lot of questions and answers here what means large traffic and large table. Like hundreds of GB-s and 10 million rows is not large. I guess it isn't, but i would like to start this app and i have a "simple" hosting (php, mysql, "unlimited" db size).

**Can you define size intervals, scales? ex.: "100M < rows means large"?**

I guess for example if 5000 users has got 1000 rows/user is enough to serve with this hosting. But i don't want to interrupt users with performance problems so if this user count become 500.000, i don't want to get lost in the dark and loose users.

**Where is the approximate limit, whate could make performance issues?**
(with this hosting)

Comment: Facebook also started with just one mysql server :-)

Comment: The quality of the PHP code is likely to be the biggest factor and then the database design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that for the start this should be fairly enough. As time will pass You will see whether Your project has success and brings hundreds of new users every day. If so then You will have to consider moving to a bigger hosting or to a dedicated server and after that You may consider creating a cluster of PHP and MySQL servers...

So, shortly: for the start this is enough.

To performance issues - this does not depend only on the amount of users, rows, etc. It also depends on how the webapp will be written - sure there could be done som PHP and SQL performance tuning but until You will have a webhosting You can do only a little (if any) server performance tuning.